# Should the [background] tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags

Apparently people are using the [background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/background) tag for two totally different topics. Some refer to their desktop background and others refer to running a process in the background.

It seems rather ambiguous to me.

Should we burninate the [background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/background) tag?

Answer (score 7):

After reviewing the list of topics using the "background" tag, I think it would be better if we split the tag up... [wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wallpaper) is one, and [background-process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/background-process) could be another.

Below is my opinion on what should be done, and on what already exists (but some "background" questions should go into):

#### Tags To Burnificate with Fire (and BlackList):

[background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/background)

#### Tags to Create:

[background-process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/background-process)

#### Tags Already In Existence:

[wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wallpaper)

#### Tag Aliases To Create:

(assuming the "Tags to Create" section is created)
[background-process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/background-process) <- [background-task](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/background-task)

Comment: Woot!Woot!Woot!Woot!Woot!Woot!Woot!Woot!Woot!Woot!Woot! (I typed "Woot!" and it said "10 more to go")

Comment: @rlemon: i lol'd.  :P

Comment: I agree. Additionally [tag:background] should be blacklisted so people don't recreate it all the time.

Comment: Indeed it should.  I added the "And Blacklist" part to the tags to burnificate :P