# Should we put [wallpaper] to the [background] (or vice-versa)?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have the [wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wallpaper) and [background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/background) tags. The tag excerpt of the first says:

> For questions regarding the image displayed on the desktop background.

The tag excerpt of the second says:

> Questions about using desktop backgrounds in Ubuntu.

So the tags are essentially about the same thing, i.e. about desktop wallpapers/backgrounds.

In the past [it was proposed](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2496/should-the-background-tag-be-burninated) that the [background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/background) tag should be burninated because it was also used for issues with background tasks/processes, which led to the creation of the [background-process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/background-process) tag. However, the [background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/background) tag is still in use for desktop backgrounds.

I suggest that [background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/background) should become a synonym of [wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wallpaper).

**Note:** Before synonymization (if agreed) some retagging must be done to questions that use the [background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/background) tag but should have used the [background-process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/background-process) tag instead.

Comment: Some reference for those who may be unfamiliar with the process: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/662263

Comment: +1 another synonym could be [desktop-background]

Comment: I have joined in moving relevant tags from background to background-process. Looks complete now?

Comment: Perhaps a week (from the time of posting of this question) is enough time to allow for comment before making the more definitive changes?

Comment: A problem I identify is that "wallpaper" seems to presume a graphic bitmap image. That may not be accurate / inclusive enough of use cases, where a flat color is used for a desktop background. The term "Background" is not only inclusive of this scenario, but Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome 3.36 uses this term in the settings app. (To complicate things a bit: on this desktop, the flat-color background has to be implemented with a bitmap image, because the feature to simply enter a hex color value had been dropped.)

Comment: @Levente I see that the wallpaper tag has this description in the 'Usage guidance (excerpt)': 'For questions regarding the image displayed on the desktop background. ' It would be a fudge but perhaps this could be extended a little: 'For questions regarding the image *or solid colour* displayed on the desktop background. ' This could be explained further in the currently non-existent full tag wiki...

Comment: Not sure if any more Community input will be forthcoming, we should proceed I suspect...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us make the main tag [desktop-background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/desktop-background) so as to be as unambiguous as possible, and let [background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/background) and [wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wallpaper) be synonyms of that.

Comment: I have made the changes above...

Comment: @andrew.46 Thank you!